# Crystal Reports Sort by difference of sub groups

Tags: sorting, crystal-reports

I'm looking for a way to sort a group by the difference of it's sub Groups

For example, Ticket is a group, Week is a group under ticket,

Ticket A : Total 100 Tickets, Difference 10 tickets

Week 1 : 55 Tickets

Week 2 : 45 Tickets

Ticket B : Total 100 Tickets, Difference 30 tickets

Week 1 : 65 Tickets

Week 2 : 35 Tickets

Ticket C : Total 150 Tickets, Difference 70 tickets

Week 1 : 110 Tickets

Week 2 : 40 Tickets

So basically, I want to determine the difference between the 2 groups, then sort by that. I can create the formula simple enough, but it won't let me sort by it.  Any ideas

Answer (score 0):

Do you have direct access to the database? For example, if this is a SQL database, I would create a stored procedure that creates the calculations for each group. Then when you add the stored procedure to the report you could easily sort them.

Some functionality is easier to produce on the db side instead of Crystal.