# Crystal Reports Running Total

Tags: crystal-reports, cumulative-sum

I have kind of a unique situation in a CR report I am writing. I am keeping a running total for a certain condition, but after all records have been processed, I then need to add the value of the running total back into a field for a specific record.

I did this by creating a formula field, and when the record meets my criteria, I add the running total to it's original value. The problem is that at the time that this record is processed, my running total is 0. Is there any possible way to go back and update a details field after all records have been processed? Or some other way I can get the total I need, before all records have been processed?

Answer (score 0):

Not really a unique situation.  Sounds like you want to do all the processing on the server then run the report against the results.
Create a database procedure and summary table.  The procedure will update the summary table which will be reported on via crystal.

Comment: similar question/answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17175764/crystal-reports-sort-by-difference-of-sub-groups/17201187#17201187